# Recovering the Zariski topology from the Zariski topology over an extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, absolute-galois-group

Suppose $A$ is a $k$-algebra, with $k$ a field, and let $\ell$ be a field extension of $k$. Is there an easy way to see/recover $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ in/from $\mathrm{Spec}(A \otimes_k \ell)$, using the action of $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$ ? *Important special case*: $\ell$ is an algebraic closure of $k$.

To illustrate my question, let $\ell$ be an algebraic closure of $k$. Then a maximal ideal $\frak{m}$ of $A$ corresponds to an $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$-orbit of maximal ideals in $A \otimes_k \ell$ (the maximal ideals in $A \otimes_k \ell$ ''over $\frak{m}$''). Is such a thing true for the other prime ideals (and for any field extension $\ell$, not ''just'' algebraic closures) ? Is there a similar way (so using the $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$-action as above) to describe the closed sets of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ ?

Comment: Recover as a space or as a scheme? As a scheme it's just classical Galois descent, I believe.

Comment: @DenisNardin.  Only the OP can answer for certain, but I suspect the OP is asking why the morphism $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k \ell)\to \text{Spec}(A)$ is *submersive*, i.e., a subset of $\text{Spec}(A)$ is open if and only if the inverse image subset of $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k \ell)$ is open.

Comment: EGA IV$_2$, 2.3.12 (applies with $\ell/k$ an arbitrary extension of fields as in the initial part of the question, whereas "${\rm{Gal}}(\ell/k)$" doesn't make sense in general).

Comment: @ nfdc23: I changed "$\mathrm{Gal}(\ell/k)$'' in ``$\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$.''

Comment: @ Denis Nardin and Jason Starr: I expanded the statement of the question to make it more precise. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @THC.  Did you read the reference in the comment by nfdc23?  That completely characterizes the open subsets (or, equivalently, the closed subsets).  A subset of $\text{Spec}(A)$ is open if and only if the inverse image subset of $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k \ell)$ is open.

Comment: @ Jason Starr: yep -- unfortunately, I don't see the $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$-action in this formulation ... :-(

Comment: @THC.  A subset of $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k \ell)$ is the inverse image of a subset of $\text{Spec}(A)$ if and only it has equal inverse images under the two projections $\text{Spec}(A\otimes_k \ell\otimes_k \ell) \to \text{Spec}(A\otimes_k \ell)$.  For a finite, Galois extension, equality of these two inverse images is equivalent to be fixed (as a subset) by the Galois group.  Anyway, this is a different part of descent: it is not about "openness" or "closedness" of subsets, it is about which subsets are inverse images.

Comment: You are very focused on the action of ${\rm{Aut}}(\ell/k)$, but that is useless when the finite extension is non-trivial but so far from Galois that it has no nontrivial automorphisms at all (e.g., $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/3})/\mathbf{Q}$ for a non-cube integer $m$).  What is your motivation for asking about general extensions and yet trying to shoehorn the (possibly trivial) automorphism group into that case?

Comment: For the record, there is an easy elementary argument that shows that the map $spec(A\otimes_k K)\to spec(A)$, $K$ the algebraic closure of $k$, is a quotient map (on topological spaces). No need to appeal to EGA IV, 2.3.12,...

Comment: @anon: I agree that tha case $K/k$ algebraic is easy.  But the case of $K/k$ non-algebraic is useful (e.g., $k=\mathbf{Q}$, $K=\mathbf{C}$) and seems to be part of the question, and doesn't seem to reduce to the algebraic case.

Comment: @ nfdc23 (about my focus on $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$): a very important case for me is the case in which $k$ is a finite field, and $\ell$ is contained in an algebraic closure of $k$. I was hoping that $\mathrm{Aut}(\ell/k)$ would act transitively on the set of prime ideals of $A \otimes_k \ell$ over a given (arbitrary) prime ideal of $A$, and that the action then could be used to elegantly describe closed sets in $A$ ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, and let $K$ be the algebraic
closure of $k$. I explain how to recover $spec(A)$ from $spec(A\otimes K)$.
Equivalently, I explain how to recover $spm(A)$ from $spm(A\otimes K)$ (max specs).
Consider the map $spm(A\otimes K)\rightarrow spm(A)$.

(a) The map is surjective.
Every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$ is the kernel
of a $k$-algebra homomorphism $A\rightarrow K$,
which extends to a $K$-algebra homomorphism $A_{K}\rightarrow K$, 
whose kernel is a maximal ideal lying over $\mathfrak{m}$.

(b) The map is continuous. Let $S=Z(f_{1},\ldots,f_{s})$ be
closed in $spm(A)$. Then $\pi^{-1}(S)=Z(f_{1},\ldots,f_{s})$ in
$spm(A_{K})$.

(c) The map is closed. Let $T=Z(f_{1},\ldots
,f_{s})$ be a closed subset of $spm(A_{K})$. Choose a basis
$(e_{j})_{j\in J}$ for $K$ as a $k$-vector space, and write
$f_{i}=\sum_{j}e_{j}f_{ij}$ (finite sum) with $f_{ij}\in A$. Every maximal
ideal of $A_{K}$ is the kernel of a $K$-algebra
homomorphism $A_{K}\rightarrow K$, and the $f_{i}$
map to zero under such a homomorphism if and only if every $f_{ij}$ does.
Therefore $T=Z(\ldots,f_{ij},\ldots)$ in $spm(A_{K})$, and it
follows that $\pi(T)=Z(\ldots,f_{ij},\ldots)$ in $spm(A)$.

Thus, the map is a quotient map of topological spaces, and the fibres are the
orbits of $Aut(K/k)$.

Comment: The OP does not assume that the $k$-algebra $A$ is *finitely generated*.

Comment: @Jason Starr. This is the key case.

Comment: "This is the key case."  I do not understand this comment.

Comment: @anon: when $A$ is a general $k$-algebra, closed subsets of ${\rm{Spec}}(A)$ don't arise from ${\rm{Spec}}(A_0)$ for a finitely generated $k$-subalgebra $A_0 \subset A$, but rather are just an intersection of such pullbacks.  Thus, there is no evident argument to reduce the problem to the case of finitely generated $A$; i.e., in what precise sense is this "the key case"?  (This is just an elaboration on Jason Starr's comment.)